# Virtuemart Terms & Conditions' Link's href attribute in Helix Template

Tags: joomla-2.5, templates, virtuemart, helix3

I'm fixing a client's website...
His website uses Joomla 2.5 and VM 2.
His template is Shaper II store, from Helix...

In the cart-view, there's a link before buying button called: Read terms and conditions...
Its href is "/".

I have tried to modify it changing the default.php file that's in /components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl.
But nothing changed...
So, I suppose Helix uses another php file for the cart-view...

After that, I tried to modify it using JQuery. I used the next code:

```
$("#link-ID").attr("href", "new-HREF");
```

But it didn't work either... So... any idea about how to change the damn href value?

Comment: When writing your jQuery, did you wrap the code around `document.ready()` ??

Comment: Yes, of course. And I also checked out if the JQuery file where I write it was implemented in that part of the website

Comment: Have you checked in the template's html folder for any overrides?